# Nested Java Interfaces

Tags: java, android, interface

I've seen this interface declaration in https://developer.android.com/training/basics/network-ops/connecting.html:

```
public interface DownloadCallback<T> {
    interface Progress {
        int ERROR = -1;
        int CONNECT_SUCCESS = 0;
        int GET_INPUT_STREAM_SUCCESS = 1;
        int PROCESS_INPUT_STREAM_IN_PROGRESS = 2;
        int PROCESS_INPUT_STREAM_SUCCESS = 3;
    }
    void updateFromDownload(T result);
    ...
}
```

As per https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/interfaceDef.html, interface body can only contain

abstract methods

default methods

static methods

constant declarations

In this case, the interface body contains another interface. How do you interpret this code block? Can someone please point me to the right documentation so I can learn more about this approach?

Comment: https://www.javatpoint.com/nested-interface

Comment: weird that the official oracle docs did not include this.

Comment: @user1506104 That's a tutorial which does not mention all the possibilities.

Comment: where do you guys check the complete java language docs? thanks anyway. sorry to bother you with this useless question. better remove this now.

Comment: @user1506104 I think the question is fine.

Comment: The words 'can only contain' do not appear in your citation. You made them up. In any case, you can't cite tutorials as normative references. They aren't. You can only cite the language specification. If a tutorial disagrees with it, it's wrong, by definition. @user1506104

Comment: @user1506104 *where do you guys check the complete java language docs?* - ultimately [JLS](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/index.html) (not sure if Android has its own thing, probably).

Comment: thank you guys. i've learned a very important lesson today. cheers! ^.^

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [JLS §9.1.4](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-9.html#jls-InterfaceBody):

> The body of an interface may declare members of the interface, that is, fields (§9.3), methods (§9.4), classes (§9.5), and interfaces (§9.5).

Usage is simply `OuterInterface.NestedInterface`.

In the code you've quoted the nested interface is only used to contain the constants so that they don't "leak" to classes implementing `DownloadCallback`.